# Text magnifying glass hangs with UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField` that I put into a `UITableViewCell` that I put into a grouped `UITableView`. I noticed today that if I hold my finger down to bring up the iPhone magnifying glass, if my `UITextField`'s keyboard type is `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`, the magnifying glass is displayed, but it just hangs - I can't move it left or right, I can't make it disappear, it just hangs.

I thought to myself, hmm, odd, maybe it's something to do with `UITextFields` in cells in a grouped `UITableView`? So I tried on some other `UITextFields`, and this does not happen for ones that do not use `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is this just a bug in Cocoa Touch? Or is there something I could possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same behaviour although my UIKeyboardType is just normal text - so its not the type of keyboard.

I too have a grouped table - and my text field is on the first row (not sure if this is relevant but thought it might help spot similarities).

**Update** - I noticed that when testing with the 3.0 sdk - I don't get this error (so it seems like something apple has fixed?). I have gone back and tried compiling with 2.2.1 and 2.2 and I still get the error on both of these versions.

I have discovered a fix described here: [Editing a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376372/editing-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uitableviewcell-fails)