# RealTime: Adding rows to the table in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I just checked the datasource and the UITableView of the app and they seem to be working well.
I can add a row to the TableView by using the code - [...initWithObjects:(id),nil] and I could do this at code level.

This is what I want to do.

1. Create an Add button or a '+' sign on top of the table.
2. So while the App is running.. If I click that, I should be able to set a name for that row.
3. If I need to create more rows and set names for them, I just press the add button and I again type new names for the rows .

How do I go about this in real time?

Comment: I got the answer here. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3481-uitableview-tutorial-part-2-a.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UITableView method `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is used to add rows to a table programmatically.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196436/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-adding-new-cells) addresses your problem fairly directly.

Comment: And don't forget the model/data source too.

Comment: But I don't have a UITableView, only a UITableViewController.

Comment: Found it; [self tableView].

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward... and this is from memory, so I might have a typo here or there. The idea should work though.

In `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you give return [myArray count] + 1; (you're adding one row to the total)

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the cell where [indexPath row] == [myArray count] is where make a cell with "Add Row" text, rather than whatever your data source is, because it goes to [myArray count]-1. (I think that makes sense).
for example,

```
    if([indexPath row] == [myArray count]){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Item";
    } else {
         cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]
                                           valueForKey:@"title"];            
    }
    return cell;
```

Then you would insert the new record into your myArray and the table.

As for actually changing the new row details, you have some options of creating a custom cell with some kind of textual input or using a modal view controller with a prompt. It's really up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I had been adding an extra row and making the mistake of [indexPath row] > [myArray count]