# UITableView action row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

On the WWDC 11 video 'session 125 - UITableCiew Changes, Tips, Tricks' at 24:30+ Mr Luke Hiesterman is giving a demo which adds a cell to the table view when a cell is selected.

[image: Screenshot from the video]

I want to add that functionality to my IOS application, but I can't figure out how to make it.

Some code is not shown in the demo-video. And there is no downloadable source of the demo.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:

I can add a new row below the selected row but it is an other custom cell.

(I have a list of contracts which you can accept)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ((indexPath.row >= [_contracts count]) ? 40 : 60);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_contracts count] + ((_addedRow) ? 1 : 0);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *reuseID = @"contract_cell";

    ContractTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseID];

    if(!cell)
    {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContractTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contract_cell.png"]]];
    }

    NSLog(@"row?: %d", indexPath.row);
    //I thought this would work... not.
    if((indexPath.row >= [_contracts count]))
    {
        [cell.label setText:@"new"];
    }
    else
    {
        Contract *contract = [_contracts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell.label setText:@"test"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(!_addedRow)
    {
        _addedRow = YES;

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

        [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

For example I press the first row. A row is added below the first one. But now the cellForRowAtIndexPath.. is called for row 2 (needs to be the new custom)

how can I check if it is a new one?

Comment: You should be calling [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] at the beginning and end of your insertions/deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember which of your rows is selected to show the added row at the correct index. Currently you're always assuming that the added row is the very last one because you're configuring it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` only if the index is bigger than your number of contracts.

Say you have five contracts and the third one is selected. `if((indexPath.row >= [_contracts count]))` is only true for the last row but actually want this condition to be true for the fourth row, so it should be `if (indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex + 1)` (you need to store the selected row index in some instance variable).

Comment: I Got is half working. The problem is checking when pressed on the same cell (so delete the added cell) and if pressed on a other cell the previous added cell has to be deleted and a new one on the current has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should help you out. It tells you how to put your UITableViewController into "update mode" and then lets you insert new rows (even with animation): [UITextField in UITableViewCell - adding new cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196436/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-adding-new-cells)