# UITableView insert row below tapped cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm extremely confused. I have looked at several posts to try to figuere out how to do this. What i would like to do is detect when a `UITableViewCell` is tapped and then insert a row right below that row with a menu.

I implemented detecting the tapped item but I can't figure out how to insert the new row right below the row that was just tapped.

Here is the method that handles the tapped cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    indexPath = nil;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Locations *location = nil;


    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        location= [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"location : %@" ,location.locationName);
        [self.locations addObject:@"New Entry"];


        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        //[self.tableViewForScreen insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        location = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"location : %@" ,location.locationName);
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



     // set the tapped item pointer equals to the locations mutable array variable wich essentially is the
    //  data source of the table view.
    //Locations *tappedItem =[self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //access the location name and print to log.



}
```

Obviously it fails at the part of insert

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Can someone give me a hand?

The error is the following.

> reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (154)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (154), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here's a post that I looked at.
[UITableView action row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805463/uitableview-action-row#8203;uitableview-action-row)
http://adcdownload.apple.com//videos/wwdc_2011__sd/session_125__uitableview_changes_tips_tricks.m4v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that you call `insertRowsAtIndexPath:` but you don't first update the data source to include the data for the new row.

You seem to do this correctly when selecting a row in the search table but not the main table.

Comment: Thanks maddy i kind of though that but arent i doing that here `[self.locations addObject:@"New Entry"];`

Comment: But that's for the search table. You don't do that for the main table (inside the `else` part of your `if` statement).

Comment: thank you maddy that is exactly what the problem was. one more question if you dont mind i like to insert a custom cell right after the tapped cell. now im just picking up the indexpath of the current cell how can i say like indexpath+1?

Comment: Create a new indexPath: `NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use

```
indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

you can take indexPath from method parameters

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It seems that you have problems because you are calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` but you are not updating data source.