# Allow user to edit UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, touch

When using a `UITableView`, is it possible to have a user touch a `UITableViewCell`, have a keyboard appear, then have `cell.textlabel.text` disappear and be replaced with the users own input from the keyboard?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376372/editing-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uitableviewcell-fails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409928/how-do-i-make-a-uitableviewcell-editable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell http://www.google.com/search?q=editable+uitableviewcell

Comment: You can refer this link. http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/uitableview.html