# UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a standard `UITableViewController`. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I add a subview to `cell.contentView`. This `UIView` itself contains a `UITextField` object. This object will not respond to touches. I have set the delegate to the UIView and implemented all the methods. I have also `set userInteractionEnabled = YES`. When I tap the `UITextField` nothing happens! I feel it's being absorbed by the cell. What would be the easiest, least messy fix?

Best,
Joris

EDIT: Sorry, see my answer. I solved it.

Comment: Post the code from cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes, just post some more code

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I hadn't properly said the UIView's frame. It of course did display the UI elements, but wouldn't respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding the textfield as a subview of the cell, this is what I have done in a couple of my apps and had no problems with it

Answer (score 0):

In your tableView, try to set

```
allowsSelection = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the editing property of the table view to YES.
Check this answer

[Editing a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376372/editing-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uitableviewcell-fails)